# Is there any way to set JVM options project wide in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way in IntelliJ to define the default JVM options for a project? I have a new project that uses AspectJ and some reflection, so I need to add 3 JVM options to make it all work. I know I can add JVM options to the run configurations, but debugging unit tests, that's going to be a pain since you get a new run configuration for every unit test.

I don't want to set JVM options system wide since that could break stuff.

Would be cool if there was some way to tell IntelliJ, every run configuration for this project gets these extra JVM options by default.

Comment: Maybe edit the [run configuration template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#templates)?

Comment: @Abby NICE! just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

think you are looking for a module setting.
Right Click on the project >> open module setting.

[image]

Comment: don't really see any way to see the jvm options there.